# does anyone knows which Slideshow script is using Tumblr.com right now?

Tags: flash, scripting

This is the URL.

http://www.tumblr.com/

I think that its based on prototype, and is using an XML as a configuration file.

Any idea?

I'm needing and script like this, with a caption bar at the bottom.

Thanks!

PD: This is de code on at the source:

```
<div id="featured_tumblelogs" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    <a href="http://hrrrthrrr.tumblr.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/featured_tumblelogs/hrrrthrrr_375.jpg"/></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var so = new SWFObject("/swf/slideshow.swf", "featured", "600", "375", "7", "#000000");
    so.addVariable("showLogo", "false"); 
    so.addVariable("showVersionInfo", "false");
    so.addVariable("dataFile", "/index_slideshow.xml?4");
    if (so.write("featured_tumblelogs")) {
        // $('featured_tumblelogs').style.marginBottom = '25px';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's this one: http://www.monoslideshow.com/

Comment: Thanks TIM! I really want to hug you! :)